# Javascript global variables are always undefined onmouseup

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, global

I have a couple global variables that are being set to `$(this)` on mouseup of the small 1 or 2 buttons.  Based on the comparison of the global variables on mouseup my code should do something.  When I step through the code in Firebug, the variable gets set and then as I step through a couple more lines, I get the following:

> ReferenceError: little_r is not defined.

I used an `alert` to see the value of the global and its always undefined. Why is the global variable not saving the value?

[I have a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/froze1906/aSyUE/12/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason little_r (etc.) are always null is because you've added little_r as a parameter to :

```
$('.small_r').on(mouseup, function(evt, little_r) {
    alert (little_r);
if (little_r == null) {
```

therefore creating a local variable. When you try to access little_r you're accessing the local (undefined) version.

I can't see what you're ultimately trying to achieve but your problem lies with local variables shadowing your global version